# Should I use set-type for user's country info in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, set

Should I use set-type for user's country info in MySQL? Or, it is better to have an another table for that? It is going to be some kind of social network question answer thing, thus, in every page will be displayed in every post, like 15 times in every page. Also, the departments will be set-type to, like stat, math, ceit, phys, ee...

Is set-type better than having separate tables for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want a separate table only if you will want to associate some information with countries, make some relations and so on.